# Display random products depending on category

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm in the single product page of a product.
I want to show, after this product, 4 other random products with **the same category**

All I have is this: (PHP)

```html
<?php
        global $product;
        $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );

        var_dump($terms);
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 4,
        'orderby'          => 'rand',
                'post_type'        => 'product' ); 

    $random_products = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $random_products as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Can any one help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way. I checked it's worked:

```
global $product;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
    $first_term = array_shift( $terms );

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 4,
        'orderby'          => 'rand',
        'post_type'        => 'product',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( $first_term->slug )
            )
        ),
        'post__not_in' => array( $product->get_id() )
    );

    $random_products = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $random_products as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Comment: Yoo thanks man! Could you explain me the difference? Why did you made these arrays?

Comment: @Vander Are you mean this part `$first_term = array_shift( $terms );
` ?

Comment: Yes, and this one: 'tax_query' => array(
            array(

Comment: @Vander Check this please - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query